# malloc() "crashing" without returning any error (program pauses)

Tags: c, malloc

I have a piece of code in which malloc() makes the program pause, without neither really crashing, nor returning an error code (NULL).

Piece of code (has to be executed 24 times, stops at the 22th) :

```
fprintf(stderr, "malloc");
//-- copy sound
pitched_sound = malloc(sizeof(Mix_Chunk));
if (pitched_sound == NULL)
    return -1;
*pitched_sound = *orig_sound;
pitched_sound->abuf = malloc(sound->alen / note_factor);
if (pitched_sound->abuf == NULL)
    return -1;
fprintf(stderr, "mallocok.");
```

Any idea?

I'm running on a Rasperry Pi (ARM), could be related?

How could I debug this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Post your code please :)

Comment: Sorry, done (some of it)

Comment: Well, it's ok now! As I changed `sound->alen / note_factor` to the cleaner `(int)ceil(sound->alen / note_factor)`. But I'd still like to know why it didn't crash not gave no error?

Comment: Because you didn't use -Wall -Wextra